# Detect when user clicks 'Never' in Google's Smart Lock for Passwords

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords, google-signin

I am currently integrating Smart Lock into my application. I have got it working such that when a user successfully signs up for a new account, the dialog below is displayed.

[image: Save password with Smart Lock?]

I can see that when the user hits 'Save Password', the onActivityResult() method is called with resultCode = RESULT_OK. I also know that if the user either dismisses the dialog OR the user clicks 'Never', the onActivityResult() method is called with result = RESULT_CANCELLED.

I would like to know if there is any way to differentiate between the user dismissing the dialog and the user selecting 'Never'.

Answer (score 2):

I am the product manager for Smart Lock at Google. This is a valid feature request (differentiate the result code based on which action the user took - cancel via back/click outside or select "Never") and we've heard it from a number of developers. It's on the roadmap, but no specific timeline yet ... I'll update this answer when this becomes available!

Comment: Do you have any updates? Where can we find the information?